# Box Collider for animating characters

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, unityscript, augmented-reality, vuforia

I need your help about how to animate two characters using box collider when they come closer in Augmented reality by using unity and Vuforia sdk.
The thing which i want is in this video.
please help me i am really thankfull to you.
Here's the link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cTIjpo6cb6M

Comment: Why do you need box colliders? Just check distance between them.

Comment: We aren't going to write your code for you... please post some code

Comment: Adrian Krupa can you tell me please how i can check the distance between them and after desired distance animation starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Help with what? Your question isn't clear. Create box colliders for each gameobject. Let the colliders be bigger than the object that will be the distance you want them to react at. Then trigger the animation when they collide.

Answer (score 0):

Vuforia places these GameObjects that are attached to the markers in world space relative to each other. Assuming that your size in the .xml is accurate. you can use the built in Vector3.Distance Method provided.

```
if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position,otherGameObject.transform.position)<minDistance)
```